# Is it possible to call method pop with callback (laravel collections)?

Tags: laravel, laravel-collection

I have a collection that contains answers from `guzzle` HTTP client. The answers can be 404, 200 or 500.

I would like to pop objects form the collection that contains only 200 and 404 statuses and leave with the statuses 500. So, I would like something like:

```
        $done = $res->pop(function ($item, $index) {
            $statusCode = $item->getStatusCode();
            return $statusCode === 404 || $statusCode === 200;
        });
```

But it's impossible( Because the `pop` methods don't take callback. Any ideas how to make this elegantly?

Comment: Is using `filter()` would work?

Comment: I think you're looking for `reject()`: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-reject `$collection->reject(function(...){ // if true, remove from collection });` (Note, this is the inverse of `filter()`; either can work if you inverse your return logic)

Comment: Thank you, but filter is not `pop`. It will not change source collection. Am I right?

Comment: If you want to update the original collection, you can simply do `$res = $res->filter(...);` to overwrite the original collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `filter` would be a better solution if you still want to keep the responses with status 500 in the original array ([documentation here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-filter)):

```php
$done = $res->filter(function ($item) {
    return $item->getStatusCode() === 500;
});

// $done will contain only responses with 500 status code
// $res will not be touched
```

Otherwise you could use `partition` to actually split the data in two groups keeping the original array unaltered ([documentation here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-partition)):

```php
list($status500, $status200_404) = $collection->partition(function ($item) {
    return $item->getStatusCode() === 500;
});

// $status500 will contain only responses with 500 status code
// $status200_404 will contain only responses with 200 and 404 status code
// $res will not be touched
```